# How to automatically escape HTML in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, escaping

I'm just getting started with RoR (and web development in general).
I know that when outputting user-supplied data we should escape it with the `h()` helper.
Is there a way to ensure that all form data (params?) received by an action is guaranteed to be escaped automatically? (I do understand that it's a wise decision to escape HTML when displaying in a view, which I will be doing in any case ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't know if this is the answer you were looking for, but you can do this by upgrading your app to rails3  - quoting Ryan Bates "In Rails 3, however, output is escaped automatically so there’s no need to put the h method" - read the [asciicast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3) or watch the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3) :)

Comment: Thanks, that's great news on the "output" front, but I was wondering if it was possible to do the escaping such that even the action would only get HTML-escaped text? (Would love to use Rails 3.0 but there seems to be problems with mysql2 gem that doesn't work with it :( )

Comment: Seems like there is a plug for this (for RoR 2.3.7+, I believe) called rails_xss. Thanks for your inputs!